# Quering XML in SQL Server without a schema

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a database that stores a large chunk of XML containing information about installations our companies products. There is no schema defined for the XML and no one has a list of all potential tags.

Each record has hundreds of structures like this:

```
<array type="DWORD" name="m_somesetting.SMTPPorts" size="5"> 
   <set>19</set> 
   <set>1D0</set> 
   <set>14B</set> 
</array>
```

I have been asked to create a table showing each possible tag a value and a count of how many of our tens of thousands of records have that particular setting.

Does anyone know how I might automate this? I have a reasonable understanding of how to do queries against XML but I need some way to first get each tag that exists and then get each unique value that exists and finally a count of records that contain that value.

Any ideas of how to do this short of hand coding each possible tag into a query?

Answer (score 1):

UDF to create table from xml

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[XMLTable](@x XML)  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN 
WITH cte AS (  
SELECT 
        1 AS lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        + N'[' 
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
        + N']' AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
        x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
        x.query('.') AS this,         
        x.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
FROM @x.nodes('/*') a(x)  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
        c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
    CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
        CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
        CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, c.query('.') AS this,  
        c.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
        CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)  
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY p.t.nodes('*') b(c)), cte2 AS (  
                                            SELECT 
                                            lvl AS Depth,  
                                            Name AS NodeName,  
                                            ParentName, 
                                            ParentPosition, 
                                            NodeType,  
                                            FullPath,  
                                            XPath,  
                                            Position, 
                                            Tree AS TreeView,  
                                            Value,  
                                            this AS XMLData,  
                                            Sort, ID  
                                            FROM cte  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.Name, 
        p.Position, 
        CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
        p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        1, 
        SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
        + N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        NULL,  
        p.Sort,  
        p.ID + 1  
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY this.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
)  
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
        ParentName, ParentPosition,Depth, NodeName, Position,   
        NodeType, FullPath, XPath, TreeView, Value, XMLData 
FROM cte2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract all the distinct tag names from a table full of XML content rather easily:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (ID INT, XmlCOntent XML)

INSERT INTO @input VALUES(1, '<array type="DWORD" name="m_somesetting.SMTPPorts" size="5"> 
   <set>19</set> 
   <set>1D0</set> 
   <set>14B</set> 
</array>'), 
(2, '<array2 type="DWORD" name="m_somesetting.SMTPPorts" size="5"> 
   <set2>19</set2> 
   <set3>1D0</set3> 
   <set4>14B</set4> 
</array2>')

SELECT
    DISTINCT 
    Nodes.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlContent.nodes('//*') AS Tbl(Nodes)
```

Mind you: I said *easily* - not quickly. This will be churning for quite a while! But it still beats doing it all manually :-)